# Estimated delivery shown even if product is out of stock

Tags: woocommerce

I added the snippet below in order to show estimated delivery.
But this is shown even when a product is out of stock

The code is

```
 `add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_delivery_estimate');

function display_delivery_estimate() {
    $now = current_time('timestamp');
    $cutoff_hour = 13;
    $working_days = 4; 
    $delivery_date = "";
    
    $shipping_date = $now;
    
    if (date('H', $now) >= $cutoff_hour) {
        $shipping_date = strtotime('+1 day', $shipping_date); 
    }
    
    $delivery_date = $shipping_date;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $working_days; $i++) {
        $delivery_date = strtotime('+1 day', $delivery_date);

        // Skip weekends (Saturday and Sunday)
        // Here for each weekend day we add +1 day
        while (date('N', $delivery_date) >= 6) {
            $delivery_date = strtotime('+1 day', $delivery_date);
        }
    }

    echo '<p>Παραλαβή μεταξύ ' . date_i18n('l, j F', $shipping_date) . ' - ' . date_i18n('l, j F', $delivery_date) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Use `is_in_stock()`method.